# FadeIn Fadeout Function Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created two functions to accept mutiple class's and Ids to fadein and fadeout, currently it will fadeout elements fine but not fadein?

```
function fadeOut($element, cb) {
    $element.animate({opacity:0}, 800, function(){
        if (cb) cb();
    });
}

function fadeIn($element, cb) {
    $element.animate({opacity:1}, 800, function(){
        if (cb) cb();
    });
}
```

Example input

```
$("#back").click(function () {
    fadeOut($('.hideToggle, .history, .apphome, .stats, #back'));
});
$("#open").click(function () {
    fadeIn($('.hideToggle, .history, .apphome, .stats, #back'));
});
```

Comment: what is the problem with built in fadeIn and fadeOut function? you can do $(this).fadeIn() or fadeOut()

Comment: I want them to fade in and out at the same time, also to clean my code up.

Comment: can you create a fiddle of whats happening at the moment?

Comment: @Brent How can something fade in *and* out at the same time?

Comment: Is the click handler supposed to fadeIn elements fired at least? And please, use jQuery methods fadeIn()/fadeOut() instead of this useless snippet

Comment: Yeah, do you guys think this is the wrong approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you want to fadein and fadeout?

I gues you want a toggle?

```
$("#back, #open").click(function () {
    $('.hideToggle, .history, .apphome, .stats, #back').fadeToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rcw93/

Or if you want to controll them apart you can use:

```
$("#back").click(function () {
    $('.hideToggle, .history, .apphome, .stats, #back').fadeOut();
});
$("#open").click(function () {
    $('.hideToggle, .history, .apphome, .stats, #back').fadeIn();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rcw93/1/

Comment: Issue with click on open

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).fadeIn() or fadeOut()` you cannot fade in and out at the same time, you can however do one after the other using the callback function.

Comment: No need of using callback as both method put animation in queue but ya OP should use relevant methods available in jQuery

Comment: Instead of the callback you can delay the chain too with something like $(this).fadeOut().next().delay(300).fadeIn();

Answer (score 0):

USe This:

```
$("#back").click(function () {
    $('.hideToggle, .history, .apphome, .stats, #back').fadeOut();
});
$("#open").click(function () {
    $('.hideToggle, .history, .apphome, .stats, #back').fadeIn();
});
```